# Why does IntelliJ not use custom local repository for install, but only for reading?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2017.2.1 and am trying to use a custom local repository location. However, I observed that artifacts are sought for in the defined location, but whenever I install an artifact, it gets installed under the default location

```
C:\Users\username\.m2\repository\...
```

I set the custom location by checking the "Override" boxes under `Settings... > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Maven > User settings file / Local repository`.

I also checked my settings.xml and my environment variables, none of them contain a local repository location.

Comment: Why are you using a custom repository at all? Maven's biggest appeal is its conventions; why are you straying from that?

Comment: Because my C drive is full and I want to move the repository to another drive

Comment: Google "maven custom local repository"?

Comment: I found two ways: setting the path in the settings.xml did not work either though, and passing the path on the command line for every build is not what I intended to do. In my opinion it should work the way it is described in the IntelliJ docs by setting the values as I did as described in the question

Comment: Both settings.xml and IntelliJ "Override" works fine for me.

Comment: Okay if I leave the settings.xml in the original place inside the .m2 folder and specify a different local repo inside, this custom local repo is used... However I still wonder why IntelliJ uses this settings.xml even though I specified a different one